# Graph API got error 'access odata is disabled'

Tags: javascript, odata

I'm using Graph calendar API with valid token, but the service returns with error

[image]
[image]

Comment: well ... you need to enable access to O Data - without any details of the API, that's about all I can say

Comment: How to 'enable access to OData'

Comment: If only there was a site on the internet where you could type *How to Fix Access to OData is disabled when Calling Graph API* and the majick faeries would sift through the 100's of pages on the world wide web, and return a list of sites where such mysteries could be solved (kidding - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2017/04/01/how-to-fix-access-to-odata-is-disabled-when-calling-graph-api/)

Comment: I saw that blog before, I tried to run the command but failed